# Referencing a ASP.NET Core application in Class Library project

Tags: compilation, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

I have created a `ASP.NET Core` application:

```
 {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },

      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0-rc1-211161024",
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols": "2.0.0-rc1-211161024",
        "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*",
        "InviteMoi.BLL": "1.0.0-*",
        "InviteMoi.DAL": "1.0.0-*"
      },

      "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
          "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "2.2.1",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.1",
            "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin": "5.2.3",
            "Microsoft.Owin.Cors": "3.0.1",
            "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb": "3.0.1",
            "Owin": "1.0.0",
            "Thinktecture.IdentityModel": "3.6.1",
            "Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client": "4.0.1"
          },
          "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
          }
        }

      },

      "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "publishExclude": [
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
      ]
    }
```

Then I added a unit test project:

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "InviteMoi.Test Class Library",
  "authors": [ "lamloumiafif" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": { 

      }
    },

    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {

        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": { 
    "NUnit": "3.2.1",
    "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "InviteMoi.BLL": "1.0.0-*",
    "InviteMoi.DAL": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

The problem is when I'd like to add the reference of the web application in the test project, it didn't work and an exception indicates that the version of the ASP.NET Core can't be higher appears.

So how can I fix this issue?

Comment: in your unit test project.son remove dotnet5.4 and change net451 to dnx451 like it is in the application. unit test projects are applications in the same way that web apps are

Comment: @JoeAudette thanks , please post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: I've posted it as an answer Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your unit test project.son remove dotnet5.4 and change net451 to dnx451 like it is in the application. unit test projects are applications in the same way that web apps are